# Javascript subtract calculation result varies based on digit

Tags: javascript, math

I just run the following javascript calculation in browser command in chrome and i got the following outputs, What is wrong with the second one?

```
100-14.3 = 85.47
100-14.4 = 85.46000000000001 
100-14.5 = 85.5
```

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com/ All of them work fine for me on Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140

Comment: I get `100-14.4 = 85.6` in Chrome.

Comment: @George i am also using the same same version of Chrome browser